# Repairing Duplicate CSS Code With PHP Storm

Tags: php, css, formatting, phpstorm

I am using PHP Storm version 8.03 and learned from this article: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/09/search-for-code-duplicates-in-phpstorm/ that you can search for duplicate CSS code.

I have researched it, but have not found how to automatically fix this duplicate code with PHP Storm. Does it provide a way? If not, any recommendations on how to automate this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is no way to do this for CSS, but there is for PHP and Javascript. Hopefully this helps someone else with the same question!